# change jquery Bootstrap datetimepicker mindate dynamically

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker, mindate

I need to change minDate of jQuery's `datetimepicker`. Currently the value for the minDate is null on the .change() method.
I am currently using the code below:

```
jQuery('#field_bvk123').datetimepicker({
onSelect: function(department_date) 
{
$('#field_jv1rv7').datetimepicker('option', minDate, department_date);
}
});
```

Can anyone assist me here??

Comment: Can you share the fiddle of the same ? Unable to identify the issue without seeing/executing your code..

Comment: Assign some date on behalf of `mindate`,  ex: mindate: getDate()

Comment: @NeerajSharma Thanks for reply, i used getDate() but there is no any change

Comment: use this, new Date('2016',0,1)

Comment: @NeerajSharma, Still not working

Comment: go with this link, it will help you https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html

Answer (score 9):

Title says

```
    $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
      $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
    });
    $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
      $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
    });
```

taken from documentations https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ under linked pickers.